# Ember bootstrap textarea width?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to re-implement a form I previously created with hbs, this time using ember bootstrap. In replacing my hbs textarea

```
    {{textarea value=foo}}
```

with as ember bootstrap textarea.

```
    {{bs-textarea value=foo}}
```

This caused the width of my textarea to become much smaller. Looking at the documentation for ember boostrap, there doesn't seem to be any property that controls width, and it doesn't seem to read html or native bootstrap fields.

Comment: Did you tried something like this {{bs-textarea value=foo cols="x"}}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the width of the text are with CSS.

"bs-textarea" component has the classNames prperty, which is the same as the property from normal ember components, you pass it an array of class names and it will append them to the text area.